# Twitter - sign request fail

Tags: twitter, oauth, request, twitter-oauth, sign

I'm trying to get a request signed with twitter so I can get a request token and got stuck. I have used the info that twitter use in their documentation to be sure that I have formated t correctly etc. I have identical Basestring and Key but still I'm not getting the same Signature. I have looked at several other examples and I seem to have done the same thing.

Would love some help to sort this out!

Here is the code:

```
    private function sign_request($http_method, $url, $params, $oath)
    {
        // SET BASE STRING
        $sign_params    =   $this->set_sign_params($params, $oath);
        $sign_url       =   $this->set_sign_url($url);
        $base_string    =   $this->set_sign_basestring($http_method, $sign_params, $sign_url);

        print $base_string; // Output the same as the twitter example: POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3005%2Fthe_dance%2Fprocess_callback%3Fservice_provider_id%3D11%26oauth_consumer_key%3DGDdmIQH6jhtmLUypg82g%26oauth_nonce%3DQP70eNmVz8jvdPevU3oJD2AfF7R7odC2XJcn4XlZJqk%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1272323042%26oauth_version%3D1.0


        // GET HMAC-SHA1 SIGNATURE
        if($this->signature_method == 'HMAC-SHA1')
        {               
            // SET KEY
            $key = $this->set_sign_key();

            print $key; // Output the same as the twitter example: MCD8BKwGdgPHvAuvgvz4EQpqDAtx89grbuNMRd7Eh98&

            //SIGN
            $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_string, $key, true)); 

            print $signature; // DO NOT output the same as the twitter example. Twitteroutput: 8wUi7m5HFQy76nowoCThusfgB+Q= and my outout: Ewqbgi+AMRZGMcqwQTjhE5/ZD80= 
        }

        return $signature;
    }
```

What have I missed? Anyone got any Idea?

Also a "fun" thing is that if I set the signture to the one in the twitter example I still can't get a request token...

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Your base string is not the same as Twitter's. That is why you are getting different signatures.

Twitter's:

`POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3005%252Fthe_dance%252Fprocess_callback%253Fservice_provider_id%253D11%26oauth_consumer_key%3DGDdmIQH6jhtmLUypg82g%26oauth_nonce%3DQP70eNmVz8jvdPevU3oJD2AfF7R7odC2XJcn4XlZJqk%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1272323042%26oauth_version%3D1.0`

Your's:

`POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3005%2Fthe_dance%2Fprocess_callback%3Fservice_provider_id%3D11%26oauth_consumer_key%3DGDdmIQH6jhtmLUypg82g%26oauth_nonce%3DQP70eNmVz8jvdPevU3oJD2AfF7R7odC2XJcn4XlZJqk%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1272323042%26oauth_version%3D1.0`

The difference is in the `oauth_callback` variable.

Twitter's:

`oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3005%252Fthe_dance%252Fprocess_callback%253Fservice_provider_id%253D11%26`

Your's:

`oauth_callback%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3005%2Fthe_dance%2Fprocess_callback%3Fservice_provider_id%3D11%26`

Comment: Thanks alot. I had missed I needed a double encoding. Now it is identical in but the signature is still not the same :(

Comment: Add the new $base_string you have to the original question.

Comment: solved it. It was another "double encoding" issue. Thanks a lot for the help - you saved my day!!